# Checking out a github release in Eclipse egit?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

How do I set egit to pull a release from github, rather than just the master?

I'm looking to checkout a release 0.4.0.
In the attached, the item checked out isn't pulled from remote - in properties the rebase, remote and upstream branch aren't set. I got this checkout from the tags, but it isn't correct.

[image: This checkout wasn't pulled from remote]

Comment: Why do you think it is not correct? The commit `23d3472` is tagged as `v0.4.0` and also the state of your current branch `v0.4.0-branch` is the commit `23d3472`.

Comment: Purely because when that branch is selected, the properties pane for it has no upstream or other. (Not that I'm intending on committing back to the project at this stage)

Answer (score 0):

You have **already checked out the right commit**: the head of your current branch `v0.4.0-branch` is the commit `23d3472` that is tagged as `v0.4.0`.

In Git a **tag references a commit, not a branch**. One commit can be in or even the head of multiple branches. For a release, a tag instead of a branch is usually used if the release is not intended to be maintained. Instead, contributions are welcome on top of the latest stage/commit of a specific branch (to avoid merging or rebasing), mostly on the `master` or on a *dev(eloper)* branch.

In your case, to contribute to [VCVRack/Rack](https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack):

1. In GitHub **fork** the VCVRack/Rack repository (assuming you are not member of this project)
2. In Eclipse **clone** the forked GitHub repository
3. In Eclipse **commit and push** your proposed change as a **single commit** to the **`master`** branch of your forked GitHub repository (currently, there are *[177 commits to master since the `v0.4.0` tag](https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack/compare/v0.4.0...master)*)
4. In GitHub create a **[pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)** based on this commit